# Can the acetic acid base silicone sealant damage the lacquer layer of the enamelled copper wire?

Tags: copper, corrosion

I know that acetic acid silicone is not the best choice for electronics.
There is a passive audio crossover with large air core coils (70mm diameter, 20mm hole in the middle) .The coils are glued with acetic acid silicone. The board is in a vented box.
The first question:
Can the acetic acid that may be trapped under inductor, damage the lacquer layer of the copper wire and then the copper over time?
The second question: Is acetic acid silicone corrosive even after curing?

Thank you all for your replies!

Comment: Give it some time and you’ll know for sure. The acetic acid is released when curing, so you should be able to wash the board after a couple of days to remove any lingering acid.

Comment: @Aazsaa:  Do you have such a crossover that you bought, or are you going to build it and use the sealant on it?

Comment: Since you can easily choose another sealant, why take the risk?

Comment: probably depends on insulating material. [Wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet_wire#Insulation) lists several materials. PET and Polyimide are probably ok, but Polyamide i.e. Nylon, which is likely the cheapest, and perhaps also Polyurethane, would be vulnerable beyond some concentration of acetic acid, esp. when warmed up. But unclear if the silicone produces this concentration